# Запустить wine на Windows

Tags: windows, wine

Как запустить [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) на Windows?
Знаю, что не много странно звучит, но мне надо это сделать.

Comment: Собрать его в Windows и запустить, не?

Comment: А **зачем** вам это нужно? Какую проблему вы хотите решить таким образом?

Comment: Мне надо протестировать работоспособность одного приложения, ставить ubuntu не хочется.

Comment: Пытаюсь скомпилировать через MSYS2, пока не успешно.

Comment: А что вам мешает тестировать работоспособность в самой винде?

Comment: Мне надо понять работоспособность приложения через wine

Comment: VirtualBox -> Ubuntu -> Wine

Comment: @lorents, а есть основания считать, что работоспособность в вайне под виндой и под линуксом будут одинаковые?

Comment: Это не странно звучит, это безсмысленно. Поставте, как сооветуют, ВМ и там любой дистрибутив с wine.