# Компиляция Wine на Windows

Tags: wine

Как компилировать Wine на Windows с помощью MSYS2?
Знаю вопрос довольно странный, но мне так нужно.

Пробую так:

```
./configure --without-x --without-freetyp
make all
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
../../tools/winegcc/winegcc -o acledit.dll -B../../tools/winebuild -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -shared acledit.spec \
  main.o -lwine ../../libs/port/libwine_port.a
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwine
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
winegcc: gcc failed
Makefile:170: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «acledit.dll»
make[1]: *** [acledit.dll] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/wine-master/dlls/acledit»
Makefile:449: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «dlls/acledit»
make: *** [dlls/acledit] Ошибка 2
```

Comment: написано же: не найдена программа `dlltool`. посмотрите в исходниках, где она разыскивается, и есть ли она у вас (в работоспособном виде). для справки: это часть gnu/binutils, и, по идее, должна присутствовать где-то в районе всех этих `mingw*`.

Comment: контрольный вопрос: а вы вообще знаете, для чего служит программа *wine*, и что вместо этой программы используется в операционной системе *ms/windows*?

Comment: dlltool есть, но работает как-то странно, при запуске dlltool -h выдает:
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ C:\MSYS2\mingw32\bin\dlltool.exe <▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒> <▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒_▒▒▒▒▒>. для чего Wine я знаю, мне надо проверить работоспособность одного приложения для Windows на Wine.

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ в комментариях http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461079